# minikube dashboard hang after vm restart

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-dashboard

I follow [the guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/) to install a test minikube on my virtualbox of ubuntu-18.04.
It's a virtualbox on my windows computer.so I use 
sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
to start minikube.
then execute minikube dashboard ....I can access http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ with the generated token.
Everything is well by now.

BUT I need to poweroff my computer on weekends. So I stop minikube and shutdown the ubuntu vm.

```
sudo minikube stop
sudo shutdown
```

When I back to work on Monday, I can't access the dashboard UI WEB,
`sudo minikube dashboard` hangs until I press Ctrl+C.
[minikube dashboard hangs until I press Ctrl+C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHSHh.png)

How can I restore the wei ui? or is there anything I need to do before shutdown the vm?

Comment: sudo kubectl get services --all-namespaces
sudo kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
CAN see the service and pods of dashboard are running.

sudo -E minikube dashboard --logtostderr --v=5
GET I1111 15:18:36.165182   10028 dashboard.go:148] Success! I will now quietly sit around until kubectl proxy exits!
^C

Comment: Could you please tell us which version of minikube are you using?

Comment: have you tried `minikube delete` `minikube start`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`minikube dashborad` starts alongside `kubectl proxy`. The process waits for `kubectl proxy` to finish but apparently it never does, therefore the command never exits or ends. This is happening because of a security precautions. `kubectl proxy` runs underneath to enforce additional security restrictions in order to prevent DNS repining attacks.

What you can do is restart the `minikube` with a current config and data cleanup and than start a fresh new instance:

```
minikube stop
rm -rf  ~/.minikube
minikube start
```

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: @OhHiMarkyes, it work after rm -rf  ~/.minikube and restart.Thank you!

Comment: additionally delete ~/.kube folder
then delete cluster with `minikube delete`
then you can start again